# What are the guidelines on using templates via lambdas in Razor (ASP.NET MVC 4)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am not able to find anything on MSDN that sheds some light on how the following feature is supposed to be used:

```
@{ Func<String, HelperResult> a = @<div>@item</div>; }
@a("Hey!");
```

Renders as:

```
<div>Hey!</div>
```

In particular am interested in knowning:

- can it take more than one parameter?
- can I specify the name of the variable other than @item (that goes by default)?
- can I use any other type of the resulting value?

The only evidence out there is that the [HelperResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.helperresult%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) type is for internal use only, which makes me think it is not supposed to be used and renders this feature undocumented giving no guarantees that it will be there in the next release.

A general question would be can I use it or not? If so, how?

Comment: best one ive seen, which other blogs refer to, is this post by phil haack who was on the asp.net team. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx

Comment: @ckross: you should add this as an answer. OP is not likely to get a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack, who was on the ASP.NET Team, at Microsoft posted this blog post regarding templated razor delegates.

[Templated Razor Delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx)